# Combining two arrays into one object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to combine two arrays into one Object with name "data"
Didn't find any efficient way

arrays:

```
var N =[ 1, 2, 3];
var s =[ a, b, c];
```

combine them into object:

```
var data= { s:[ a, b, c], N: [ 1, 2, 3 ] };
```

Comment: `var data = {s: s, N: N};`! Or in recent ECMAScripts: `var data = {s, N};`!

Comment: `var data = { s, N };` (ES6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be:

```
const N = [1, 2, 3];
const s = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const data = { s, N };
```

This is equivalent to:

```
const N =[ 1, 2, 3];
const s = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const data = { s: s, N: N };
```

Note: I used `const` since the variables aren't reassigned.

Answer (score 1):

Do it this way:

```
var N =[ 1, 2, 3];
var s =[ a, b, c];

var obj = {N, s};
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var N =[ 1, 2, 3];
var s =[ 'a', 'b', 'c'];

var data = {s, N};
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass your arrays (N and s) as variables to your new object.
 You can do this in few ways:

1. let myObject = { N: N, s: s }
   If you do this way you can type any other key. For example:
   let myObject = { firstArray: N, secondArray: s }
   and now you can access to N and s arrays as myObject.firstArray etc
2. Use short notation:
   let myObject = { N, s }
   This code will look up for variables N and s and write it inside your new object, which will give the same result as let myObject = { N: N, s: s }